# Is it fine to create javascript-only content on my website?

Tags: javascript, static, vuejs2

I enjoy coding with Vue.js and I'd like to build my website's portfolio with it, but it would only be viewable if javascript is enabled.

I know that robots will not be able to access it for references, but I'm aiming at regular users and/or possible employers. Is it bad if I do javascript-only content then?

For now I restricted myself on developing static content and then I would integrate vue components, but what if the whole website is javascript-only? It would be nicer to navigate but what about non-javascript users?

Comment: This sort of question isn't suitable for Stack Overflow, this is opinion based. It isn't a specific programming problem.

Comment: There seems to be similar questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: What research have you done? Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Employers will be more likely to visit your personal website when referred either directly there (you send them an email with your resume) or from another larger site (linkedin, github). So I wouldn't worry too much about SEO making your website - focus on learning and showcasing your skills.

If you do want to be more visible to search engines, and learn a pretty hot new skill, consider server side rendering - that way, your JS will be available to search engines.

More here:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html